# Migration from Oracle to MariaDB - Trigger, Self-referencing table

Tags: oracle, triggers, mariadb, self-referencing-table

I'm migrating my Oracle database to MariaDB, and I am unsure how to create a self-referencing ID on one of my tables.

Essentially, if a `belongs_to_id` is not specified, it will assume that it belongs to itself (and be the same as the ID generated `ON INSERT`); however, if a `belongs_to_id` has been specified, then it will use that instead.

The reason I do this is because I have posts and replies stored in the same table.  If the `id` = `belongs_to_id` then it's an initiating post, whereas if it differs, it is a reply to another post.

I've thought about letting my application (Node JS) do a quick `UPDATE` using last_insert_id - but it seems rather messy and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Here's what I use in Oracle - does anyone know how I replicate this in MariaDB please?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    :new.id := my_sequence.NEXTVAL;
    :new.belongs_to_id := NVL(:new.belongs_to_id,:new.id);
END;
/
```

Comment: This should work on MariaDb, have you tried it?

Comment: No! I assumed it wouldn't... Does Maria DB understand Oracle PL/SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [should work](http://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/triggers/before_insert.php) in MariaDb as it closely conforms to [SQL-99 syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/trigger-examples/).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    :new.id := my_sequence.NEXTVAL;
    :new.belongs_to_id := NVL(:new.belongs_to_id,:new.id);
END;
```

IF you set your new ID to be an auto increment then you can only use an after insert trigger.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
v_id NUMBER:
BEGIN    
    v_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
    :old.belongs_to_id := NVL(:old.belongs_to_id,v_id);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you @kevinsky - I have set the table to be an autoincrement - can I access `my_sequence` in an object somewhere? (forgive my MariaDB ignorance)

Comment: @doublesidedstickytape: Beware of the error that can occur: `Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger`.

Comment: Thank you both very much - SO should have a 'buy a pint' button :) Do you know of there are there any risks in using LAST_INSERT_ID, say if there are multiple INSERT requests please?

Comment: @doublesidedstickytape    why not make a new question?

Comment: I've had some issues with this answer with it not compiling correctly - I did get something working and I have posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800272/mariadb-self-referencing-trigger-before-insert

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply

When `INSERTing`, set belongs_to_id to `NULL` (no `TRIGGER`).
When `SELECTing`, do `COALESCE(belongs_to_id, id)`.

Meanwhile, completely switch from `SEQUENCE` to `AUTO_INCREMENT` (again no `TRIGGER`).